# Computing the powerset of a list

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, recursion, combinatorics

I've written the following code for computing the powerset of a list (we consider the list has all distinct elements, although it doesn't really matter).

Can this function be further optimized?

```
def powerset(A):
    if A == []:
        return [[]]
    a = A[0]
    incomplete_pset = powerset(A[1:])
    rest = []
    for set in incomplete_pset:
        rest.append([a] + set)
    return rest + incomplete_pset
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

This is [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel), because the [official documentation gives a recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

By using iterables it tackles the [memory-optimization](/questions/tagged/memory-optimization) issue effectively.

However, it is possibly not as efficient as it could be because of the way it splits up the work.

---

To make your code more memory efficient, you could also introduce iterables. I'm assuming that you don't care about the order:

```
def powerset(A):
    if A == []:
        yield []
    else:
        a = A[0]
        for tail in powerset(A[1:]):
            yield tail
            yield [a] + tail
```

I've chosen `tail` to avoid aliasing the built-in `set` function.

---

The fastest memory-efficient approach is probably going to be an iterable using a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) to create a non-recursive solution which adds or removes a single element to the set between each `yield`.

---

Also, FWIW, your code could be more Pythonic.

> ```
>     rest = []
>     for set in incomplete_pset:
>         rest.append([a] + set)
> ```

could be

```
rest = [[a] + tail for tail in incomplete_pset]
```

It's possible that my iterable rewrite of it could also be more Pythonic using a comprehension - I'm open to comments on this point.